# reference counting not working in shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, reference-counting

The below code results in run time error.

Each `shared_ptr` holds the same memory, but still the count for each one is one.

So, each shared pointer is different, so when they go out of scope they try to free the block and this causes corrupting the heap. My question is how to avoid this?

Just want to add declaration like this

```
shared_ptr<int> x(p);
```

is non negotiable I have to declare it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int* p = new int (10);
  shared_ptr<int> a (p);
  shared_ptr<int> b (p);
  shared_ptr<int> c (p);
  shared_ptr<int> d (p);
  cout<<"Count : "<<a.use_count()<<endl;
  cout<<"Count : "<<b.use_count()<<endl;
  cout<<"Count : "<<c.use_count()<<endl;
  cout<<"Count : "<<d.use_count()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `shared_ptr<int> b = a;` etc.? That's the only way to actually have a *shared* pointer, otherwise you might just as well not use the new smart pointers at all.

Comment: Also, I recommend you don't simply look at the smart pointers as "self-deleting pointers", but in terms of *ownership* instead. Can a resource or thing only have a single owner at a time? Then use `std::unique_ptr`. Can a resource or thing has multiple simultaneous owners? Then use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Lastly, in programming *nothing* is "non negotiable".  If the features of the current programming language or framework you are using doesn't fit your requirements, then either the requirements or the language/framework has to be changed.

Comment: Forgive me, but the phrase 'is non negotiable I have to declare it' made me chuckle, if you declare like that multiple times, your code will be broken, THAT is non-negotiable ;)

Answer (score 10):

You may only crate a smart pointer from a raw one if you have ownership over the pointer. As soon as you create the smart pointer, the ownership will have been passed to the smart pointer. Since you no longer have the ownership, you may not create additional smart pointers from the raw pointer.

To get a shared pointer to memory that is already managed/owned by a shared pointer, you must copy from the existing shared pointer:

```
shared_ptr<int> b = a;
shared_ptr<int> c = a;
// ....
```

If you simply create multiple shared pointers from the raw pointer, then none of those shared pointers will know about the existence of each other, and all of them will believe to be the sole owner of that memory and the problems you describe will occur.